# What's the best language to use for a simple windows 7 dynamic gui desktop app

Tags: programming-languages, text-editor

[Note: I hope I am not breaking etiquette, but I originally posted a variant on this question [here](https://superuser.com/questions/494851/creating-or-discovering-a-very-simple-multiple-frame-text-organizing-program), but am re-asking here because I am making this now solely a question about programming.]

I would like to program of the following simple form:

1. The user can produce X number of resizable frames (analogous to HTML frames).
2. Each frame serves as a simple text editor, which you can type into and save the whole configuration including resized windows and text.
3. The user should be able alternately "freeze" and present the information, and "unfreeze" and edit frames.

Thus it will be a cross between a calendar and a text editor. I don't particularly care if it is a web application or not. What languages are ideal for such a setup? I know some C and Python and Html, and am willing to learn others if need be. It seems to me this should be a relatively easy program to make, but I need a little direction before starting.

EDIT: My OS is Windows 7.

Comment: You need to specify os, it makes a huge difference when deciding desktop GUI app languages. For windows C# with wpf is a great bet, but it may be Java or c++ with qt for Linux (I don't know) or mac it would be iduno? Cocoa?

Comment: Thanks, I've added that. Windows 7. Would be great if you could expand that into an answer, I'm not too familiar with those things and what tools in particular would be of use to my goal.

Comment: The problem with questions like this is that your requirements are such that most any programming language can be used to achieve this easily.  Everybody will simply post an answer soliciting their favorite programming language.  This is why it was closed as Not Constructive.

Comment: I wasn't aware that this could be done *easily* in all languages.

Comment: @GregorSamsa Easy is fairly subjective and dependent on peoples personal tastes and preferences.

Comment: I understand. I am only speaking about my ignorance. I guess I should have asked about the possibility that this could be done in any language. That would have also answered my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could potentially use any language out there. If you're looking for a free option, WPF would be a great choice, and you get the bonus of incredibly beautiful interfaces (provided you put enough effort and time into it).

If you're willing to sink some cash into it, Embarcadero offer C++ Builder and Delphi, both of which can take advantage of/ship with the Firemonkey framework which is similar to WPF, except it's exceptionally easy to create "custom components" via styling. If your example, you could simply composite the text box/memo inside a `TSelection` which would allow them to resize and move the frames around, save it inside a `TStylebook`, and then reference that style when you create the object (presumably at runtime, unless you want to have a specific, and small, amount of frames).

Actually saving the positions is exceptionally easy in just about any language, and the use of a `TIniFile`, or a `TMemIniFile` (due to it not being limited to 64KB file size), or even better by using JSON, would make this part very easy. "Locking and unlocking" of frames would also be done similarly across languages by simply toggling the `enabled` property of the frame.

You'd be able to run this application created in Firemonkey on any Windows OS from XP right up to and including 8, as well as various versions of Mac OS X. As said, you would need to sink some cash into it, but they do offer a free trial for it. I've personally used the above advice in my own applications, so i can vouch for it being possible (and very easy), but there's numerous options out there and your task is a relatively easy one.

Comment: I'd probably go with the free option, but if I go with the "sinking cash" option, are you saying to get *both* C++ Builder and Delphi, or one or the other?

Comment: I'd settle with one OR the other, not both. I say that there's Delphi and C++ available on the simple basis that it allows freedom of choice (and C++ is certainly the more popular of the two).